# FilePicker.io Cloud service authentication fails for android api

Tags: android, filepicker.io

Today I started implementing filepicker.io in my android native application, but i've ran into a strange bug (**that i confirmed that exists also in the sample projects**, like notepad master).

The activity works fine (as in it shows the import type chooser) however whenever i try to authenticate to a cloud service (google drive, dropbox, etc) i get this:

```
05-15 14:48:05.330: W/System.err(781): io.filepicker.AuthError
05-15 14:48:05.330: W/System.err(781):  at             io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI.parseFolder(FilePickerAPI.java:228)
05-15 14:48:05.350: W/System.err(781):  at io.filepicker.FilePickerAPI.getPath(FilePickerAPI.java:345)
05-15 14:48:05.350: W/System.err(781):  at io.filepicker.FilePicker$FpapiTask.doInBackground(FilePicker.java:156)
05-15 14:48:05.350: W/System.err(781):  at io.filepicker.FilePicker$FpapiTask.doInBackground(FilePicker.java:1)
05-15 14:48:05.360: W/System.err(781):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-15 14:48:05.360: W/System.err(781):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
05-15 14:48:05.370: W/System.err(781):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
05-15 14:48:05.380: W/System.err(781):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-15 14:48:05.380: W/System.err(781):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-15 14:48:05.390: W/System.err(781):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-15 14:48:05.790: W/EGL_emulation(781): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
```

I would put my code here, but since it also happens with the notepad sample project i think its a server-side problem.

Gallery file retrieval works fine. It just happens with cloud services, during authentication.

Any help would be good.

Comment: I solved my problem by using the first commit for this project. The version 1.0.0. from July 2012 works perfectly, so somewhere between there and the last version something went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with the recent filepicker.io library for Android. The solution from user2386435 works for me too. So in addition this is the [mentioned revision from 12. July 2012](https://github.com/Ink/filepicker-android/tree/df563a136c85f38371ddd42a0af333dd7e912702).

Answer (score 0):

This issue is solved now in the latest version of FilePicker Android Library.

You can check it out on [github](https://github.com/Ink/filepicker-android)